# Как отсортировать кортежи по двум ключам в python?

Tags: python, сортировка

Задача такова: дан массив кортежей, он называется array, кортежи нужно отсортировать по элементу с индексом n, а затем те из них, у кого этот элемент одинаковый, по элементу с индексом m.

Если нужна сортировка по одному параметру, то, понятно,

`array = sorted(array, key=lambda tup: tup[n])`

А вот что делать, если, как описано, два параметра "разной значимости"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array = sorted(array, key = lambda tup: (tup[n], tup[m]))`